# Fazer delete via php

Tags: php

Estou programando uma página em php e estou com a seguinte duvida fiz um *insert* no meu banco de dados e criei uma `<table>` a dentro dele estão sendo exibidos meus dados esse seria o código:

```
 <table id="tb1" class="display" cellspacing="0">
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Produto</th>
                    <th>valor</th>
                    <th>data</th>
                    <th>apagar</th>
                </tr> 
            </thead> 

            <tbody id="tbody">
                <?php
                    include ('conection/config.php');

                    $conn = mysqli_connect ($varBDhostname,$varBDusername,$varBDpassword,$varBDdatabase);

                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT *FROM tbl_produtos') or die(mysqli_error());
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                 ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row["id"]?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["nome"]?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["valor"]?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["dh"]?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

minhas conexões estão funcionando normalmente porem precisaria colocar uma coluna que contenha um botão de deletar só que minha duvida e a seguinte deverei fazer uma nova conexão pois eu percebi que minha tag `<tr>` está dentro do while que faz o select logo não sei onde ficaria a do delete sendo que deveria aproveitar a mesma tabela pelo menos é oque eu acho como poderia fazer esses deletes

### Fiz esse delete e aqui:

```
<header class="header">
        <form action="conection/inserir.php" method="post" id="form">
            <h1>Inserir Produtos</h1>
            <input type="text" name="nome" id="produto" placeholder="Produto" maxlength="30" required/>
            <input type="number" name="valor" id="valor" placeholder="valor" maxlength="10" required/>

            <input type="submit" value="cadastrar" name="cadastro">
        </form>

        <?
            include ('conection/config.php');
            $conn = mysqli_connect ($varBDhostname,$varBDusername,$varBDpassword,$varBDdatabase);

            if(isset($_GET['deletar'])): 
                $id = $_GET['deletar'];
                $delete = mysqli_query($conn,'DELETE FROM tbl_produtos WHERE id = {$id}') or die(mysqli_error());

                    if($delete):
                        echo "Registro removido";
                        endif;
            endif;

            ?>

        <table id="tb1" class="display" cellspacing="0">
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Produto</th>
                    <th>valor</th>
                    <th>data</th>
                    <th>apagar</th>
                </tr> 
            </thead> 

            <tbody id="tbody">
                <?php

                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT *FROM tbl_produtos') or die(mysqli_error());
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                 ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row["id"]?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["nome"]?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["valor"]?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["dh"]?></td>
                    <td><a href="?deletar=<?php echo $row["id"]?>">Deletar</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

### E deu esses erros aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Conexão se faz uma vez só no topo da página.
Não precisa chamar de novo o arquivo.
Coloque uma outra coluna `td` com o LINK para deletar.

Comment: quando voce fala link sera um href

Comment: Exatamente. `<a href="deletar.php?cod=<?php echo $row['id']?"> Deletar </a>`

Comment: @Kirito Postei uma resposta. Note que inseri a conexão no topo do arquivo e elaborei um href para que consigas buscar o Id do registro e faça a exclusão conforme o id passado.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar dessa forma:

```
<?
include ('conection/config.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect ($varBDhostname,$varBDusername,$varBDpassword,$varBDdatabase);

if(isset($_GET['deletar'])): 
    $id = $_GET['deletar'];
    $delete = mysqli_query($conn,'DELETE FROM tbl_produtos WHERE id = {$id}') or die(mysqli_error());

        if($delete):
            echo "Registro removido";
            endif;
endif;

?>

<table id="tb1" class="display" cellspacing="0">
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Produto</th>
            <th>valor</th>
            <th>data</th>
            <th>apagar</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead> 

    <tbody id="tbody">
        <?php




            $result = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT *FROM tbl_produtos') or die(mysqli_error());
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
         ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["id"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["nome"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["valor"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["dh"]?></td>
            <td><a href="?deletar=<?php echo $row["id"]?>">Deletar Registro</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

A não ser que você tenha alguma função de deletar ou esteja trabalhando com algum framework, mas na base, seria isso... 
Creio que deverá solucionar sua questão e dúvida.

Comment: amigo editei a minha pergunt e adicionei oque vc disse mais da um erro da uma olhadinha

Comment: na segunda linha, tente fazer o seguinte: if($conn){ echo "conectado"; } else { echo "sem conexao"; }

Comment: vc diz na sugunda linha onde vc tem aquela condicao  if(isset($_GET['deletar'])): ou  $conn = mysqli_connect ($varBDhostname,$varBDusername,$varBDpassword,$varBDdatabase);

Comment: pode colocar antes desse if(isset($_GET['deletar'])): , coloque: if($conn){ echo "conectado"; } else { echo "sem conexao"; } –

Comment: coloquei e nada amigo

Comment: Mas aparece conectado?

Comment: nao aparece nao amigo olhei bem aqui e nao aparece

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26813/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-kirito).

Comment: ok amigo ja tou logado la no chat[